# Restrict a physical NIC or VLAN to a specific process?

Tags: windows, vlan, nic

On a Windows operating system, is there any way to have an isolated network interface or VLAN, that is only authorized to communicate with specific processes?

The interface or VLAN would be effectively hidden from all other system processes and to the rest of the system the privileged-access network interface / VLAN would not seem to be installed or accessible.

I have never heard of this, and it is probably not possible.

The closest alternative would be a virtual machine with a virtual adapter assigned to it, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: what should be the affors of it? i am preety sure in my opinion that it is not possible without third party tools

Comment: You can restrict the *use* of a particular network interface to a specified executable or executables via the Windows Firewall.  There's no built-in way to hide the fact that the interface exists, Windows just doesn't work that way.  What is your use case?